# Rotating chevrons with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a chevron rotate 180deg when clicking on its parent element to indicate whether a section is expanded or collapsed to an existing (non-bootstrap) accordion.

Currently all sections are defaulted to display expanded (green). When the .BlackTitleExp_top_style div is clicked the header section closes and the divs bg-color turns a light green to indicate the section is collapsed.

Ideally, when the header turns grey, the chevron should also rotate 180deg so that is is pointing down indicating the section is closed.

Ideally I'd like to accomplish by clicking on BlackTitleExp_top_style  parent element but I'm not married to this idea. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var BTE_top = $(".BlackTitleExp_top_style");
  var BTE_top_BG = "BlackTitleExp_top_style_BG";

  $(BTE_top).click(function() {
    var el = $(this);

    el.not(el).removeClass(BTE_top_BG);
    el.toggleClass(BTE_top_BG);
  });
});
```

```css
.BlackTitleExp_top_style {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(92, 132, 92, 0.35);
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.BlackTitleExp_top_style_BG {
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.35);
}
.chevron {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="BlackTitleExp_top_style">
    simulated open section
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up chevron"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="BlackTitleExp_top_style">
    simulated open section
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up chevron"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="BlackTitleExp_top_style">
    simulated open section
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up chevron"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="BlackTitleExp_top_style">
    simulated open section
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up chevron"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just swap `fa-chevron-up` to `fa-chevron-down`?

Answer (score 1):

Define the states that an element(s) can exist in (ex. rotated 180<sup>o</sup>/0<sup>o</sup>, expanded/collapsed, 
on/off etc) then declare the [condition(s)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling) (ex. `if (fart) { smell.it })` or [event(s)](https://eloquentjavascript.net/15_event.html) (ex. click, hover, etc) that can occur to invoke a behavior(s) (ex. rotate, expand, do your taxes, etc). In the demo below the adding/removing of a class (`.fa-rotate-180`) sets the styles on each `<i>`.

The class [`.fa-rotate-180`](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/rotating-icons) is a Font Awesome class that will rotate any of its icons 180<sup>o</sup> when applied. CSS animation is added as well via [`transform: rotate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate), [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions), and [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

**Details commented in demo**

```js
// Start with all content hidden
$('.content').hide();

// When header.title is clicked...
$('.title').on('click', function(event) {

  // Reference the p.content that follows the clicked header✱
  const clickedContent = $(this).next('.content');
  // Reference the i.chevron that is nested within clicked header
  const clickedChevron = $(this).find('.chevron');
  
  /* Slide up all p.content with the exception of the sibling p.content that follows
    the clicked header✱ */
  $('.content').not(clickedContent).slideUp('fast');
  
  // Expand/Collapse the p.content of the clicked header✱
  clickedContent.slideToggle('fast');
  
  /* Remove .fa-rotate-180 class from all i.chevron with the exception of the 
     i.chevron nested within clicked header */
  $('.chevron').not(clickedChevron).removeClass('fa-rotate-180');
  
  /* Add/Remove .fa-rotate-180 class to/from the i.chevron nested within the 
     clicked header */
  clickedChevron.toggleClass('fa-rotate-180');
});

/* ✱ The expand/collapse aspect of code is not required by OP question and 
   is only added to provide a complete functional example. */
```

```css
:root {
  font: 16px/1.2 Arial;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  cursor: pointer
}

.chevron {
  /* block or inline-block for smoother animation */
  display: inline-block;
  /* Animation when going back to collapsed state */
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.fa-rotate-180 {
  /* This declares the keyframes used for animation */
  animation: spin;
  transition: 0.4s
}


/* An @rule used to breakdown animation into steps */

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<aside class='read-more'>
  <header class='title'>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up chevron"></i> Chevron rotates 180<sup>o</sup>...
  </header>
  <p class='content'>...when header is clicked</p>
</aside>

<aside class='read-more'>
  <header class='title'>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up chevron"></i> Chevron rotates 180<sup>o</sup>...
  </header>
  <p class='content'>...when header is clicked</p>
</aside>

<aside class='read-more'>
  <header class='title'>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up chevron"></i> Chevron rotates 180<sup>o</sup>...
  </header>
  <p class='content'>...when header is clicked</p>
</aside>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
BTE_top.click(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var icon = el.find('i');

    if(!icon.hasClass('rotate')){
        icon.addClass('rotate');
    }

    el.not(el).removeClass(BTE_top_BG);
    el.toggleClass(BTE_top_BG);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. Just adding this little bit of CSS will get you what you want:

```
.chevron {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.BlackTitleExp_top_style_BG .chevron {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Now when the `BlackTitleExp_top_style_BG` is added, the `chevron`s `transform` property is updated. With a `transition` now defined on `chevron` the rest of your code works as expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var BTE_top = $(".BlackTitleExp_top_style");
  var BTE_top_BG = "BlackTitleExp_top_style_BG";

  $(BTE_top).click(function() {
    var el = $(this);

    el.not(el).removeClass(BTE_top_BG);
    el.toggleClass(BTE_top_BG);
  });
});
```

```css
.BlackTitleExp_top_style {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(92, 132, 92, 0.35);
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.BlackTitleExp_top_style_BG {
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.35);
}
.chevron {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.BlackTitleExp_top_style_BG .chevron {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="BlackTitleExp_top_style">
    simulated open section
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up chevron"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="BlackTitleExp_top_style">
    simulated open section
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up chevron"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="BlackTitleExp_top_style">
    simulated open section
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up chevron"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="BlackTitleExp_top_style">
    simulated open section
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up chevron"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```